# Finding order of pole, why is this argument not valid?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, singularity, analyticity

I'm learning about different types of singularities in complex analysis, and stumbled upon a problem with finding what order of pole $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}$ have at $z_0=0$.

My solution is

$$\lim_{z \to 0} ~(z-z_0)^3 \frac{\sin(z)}{z^3} = \sin(0)$$

which according to me should give me a pole of order 3, however, the correct answer is 2. Why so? Would anyone mind explain?

Comment: Your limit (well, with $z_0=0$) implies that the order of the pole is less than $3$. A limit like $\lim_{z\to0}z^mf(z)=a$, for some $a\neq0$ implies a pole of order $m$, but in your case you have $a=\sin(0)=0$.

Comment: Oh, yes of course... I see why this is not a pole of order 3, however how do I show its a pole of order 2?

Comment: Exactly the way you did, but try smaller exponents until you hit the limit that exists and is non-zero. The first next limit to try $\lim_{z\to0}z^2\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}$ already is going to be non-zero

Comment: And that is due to Taylor expansion of $\sin(z)$?

Comment: You can look at it that way, yes.

Comment: Alright, thank you :)

Comment: Note that $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at a point $z_0$ if and only if its Laurent expansion centered at that point $z_0$ takes the form $\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n} + \ldots + \frac{b_1}{z-z_0} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ where the sum of terms before the series of $a_n$ is the principal part. So in your case, one way to find the order of the pole is by expanding $\sin z$ as its series centered at $0$ and finding out what its principal part is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $g(z)=\frac {\sin z}{z}$, then

$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z^2}$$

Can you show $z=0$ in $g(z)$ is actually a removable singularity? Hence, $z=0$ is a second order pole for $f(z)$.